# Difference between project resource and local resource images

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the difference between browse an image on a windows form control from a project recource file or a local resource file? In my project I have used images from a local resource. Would it be better to have all my images in the project resource file and why?

Thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In case of local resource the image can be used only with that particular form and if you need it in some other form you have to duplicate it

whereas in project resource the image could be used across multiple forms and the there is no duplication of the file.

Comment: Thanx :) +1 for the answer

Comment: There are some additional notes on this MSDN blog post, ["Forms-Based Resources vs. Project Resources"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2006/01/31/521297.aspx), that is also good to know.

Comment: @JeffBridgman  or V4,  would you like to give this one   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405728/visual-studio-how-can-i-view-local-resource-images  a try?